# Blazor MailKit bind values to the message

Tags: c#, blazor-server-side

I have a Blazor server app and I use Mailkit to send emails. Using a model I bind and send the email to the given address.

I have the following code that i use to send emails:

```
    email.To.Add(MailboxAddress.Parse(model.ToEmail));
    email.Subject = "EEXI Calculation Results";
    email.Body = new TextPart(TextFormat.Html) { Text = "Full Name" };
```

Similarly how I bind the email address using:

```
email.To.Add(MailboxAddress.Parse(model.ToEmail));
```

I would like to bind other values from the inputs and show both text

```
email.Body = new TextPart(TextFormat.Html) { Text = "Full Name:",model.name};
```

Answer (score 0):

That's what email templates are used for, there are many ways to create and use them. Here are some useful links:

#### Custom (simple) string template:

Create email templates in code... it's very basic, but sometimes that's all you need.

```cs
public string NewUserEmailTemplate(User user, string confirmationUrl){
    return $"Welcome {user.FirstName} {user.LastName}! You are now a registered user. Please click the following url to confirm your account: {confirmationUrl}";
}
```

#### Razor page .cshtml email template

The more advanced and better way of doing email templates. Here's a link to a tutorial:
https://scottsauber.com/2018/07/07/walkthrough-creating-an-html-email-template-with-razor-and-razor-class-libraries-and-rendering-it-from-a-net-standard-class-library/